# Which type of Entity generator to use?

Tags: entity-framework

I am writing my first WPF and EF application. I am using SQL CE database and I have added few tables to the DB. The EF diagram is generated and now I want to generate the classes. I am new to EF and MVVM both.

When I right-click on a Table diagram, it gives option "Add Code Generation Item..". On selecting it, there are two options:

Add Entity Object Generator

Add Self-Tracking Entity Object Generator

I want to know what is the difference between the two. Which one should I use? I also want to know which one is latest and what is POCO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A POCO is a Plain Old CLR Object... a simple class that has only properties.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object

There are 3 approaches that the Entity Framework delivers.

- Model first (you create a model in visual studio and generate the database)
- Database first (thats what you do, you generate a model from a existing database)
- Code first (the newest one, you just write you POCOS and the entity framework generates the database)

I think it is enough to generate the diagram from database. The context and models should be available after this.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those is the POCO generator. The best way to get that is to [install Entity Framework 4.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx). You'll then see some new options in the list to add a code generation item.

I'm a pretty big fan of the DbContext/POCO generator added in 4.1 as the code it creates is VERY easy to work with compared to the older stuff, and it works well in a DB First setup like you're using (which is also what I use).

Comment: I have installed VS-2010 Express. Is EF-4.1 not available with the express edition?

Comment: Far as I know it is, but EF 4.1 isn't included with it. It's a more recent release that you have to download seperately.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this code generator a try:
http://salardbcodegenerator.codeplex.com/

It generates data annotations and implements INotifyPropertyChanged for CodeFirst approach.